# How to provide different information for same complication?

Tags: swiftui, widget, watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

How can I provide multiple complications with the same [widget family](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetfamily) using the new [WidgetKit API](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10050) for watchOS like in the screenshot?

I found a lot of old explanations, but none for the new way to create complications.

[image]